# How to use the BH1750 support in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-device-driver, i2c, iio

I'm writing code in Raspberry Pi, trying to communicate BH1750 ambient light sensor connected in a I2C port. Most working ways are using Python SMBus library but I'm writing C++ code. After some search, I found that:

- The well-known wiringPi library seems outdated and even removed from raspbian's repo.
- the `i2c-tools` is not usable, as it requires a memory mapping of client functions, but BH1750 is based on simple raw data flows.
- There are `i2c.h` and `i2c-dev.h` Linux API, so at least I can use them as a last resort.
- In Linux repo, there is a [bh1750.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/iio/light/bh1750.c) source file, so I guess there are some easy-to-use APIs and I don't need to write communication code at all. But I don't find a `bh1750.h` in `/usr/include/linux`. Instead, there is a `/usr/include/linux/iio` directory, but header files in it don't provide any function APIs and I don't know how to use it.

How can I use the BH1750 support in Linux kernel?

Comment: You need to install `libiio` which provides a rich API for the C code and IIRC there is a Python binding. But even in shell you may do some things (single reads of raw values or so) without any of the libraries at all.